# adb emulator devices isn't showing up, restarting server doesn't fix

Tags: android, xamarin, android-emulator, adb, emulation

I am running an emulated Nexus 5 running Android 5.1.0 on Xamarin, and I cannot for the life of me get adb to recognize the emulator as a device. The only way I can get the device to connect is through TCP/IP, connecting to the emulator's given IP address manually.

I've tried reinstalling the Android SDK, Xamarin, and VirtualBox (which the Xamarin emulator uses), as well as tweaking several settings in each, all of which lead to nothing.

And no, running

`adb kill-server
adb start-server`

does NOT fix the issue, like every other thread I've seen has suggested as the only fix.

I look forward to your help, and thank you in advance!

EDIT: Additionally, I should add that `adb devices` DOES recognize my physical Android device when connected through USB, but still not the emulated device.

Comment: Is this using the Xamarin Android Player? Just so you know, it is deprecated and no longer supported. See: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/debug-on-emulator/ . Have you tried other emulators? The new Google emulators are quite fast as long as you install the Intel HAXM accelerator. There is also the Visual Studio 2015 Android emulators which may be worth a shot as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Xamarin Android Player. Try following steps

1. Shut down the emulated device.
2. Open Oracle VM virtual box manager
3. Identify emulated device and open settings.
4. Go to USB tab and Enable USB Controller.
5. Save settings. And start device from Xamarin Android Player

Try different sub options from Enable USB Controller. I enabled USB 1.1 and it worked for me. I am not sure it will work for all. Let me know your experience.